# Create Table if not exists without columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to just create a table in MSSQL without columns?

I'm asking this because I'll have to check for every columns if it already exists or not.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Tags]') AND type in (N'U'))
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].Tags(
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_Tags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Id] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
    END
GO
```

The execution might break by creating the column Id if the table and the column already exists.

This would be ideally:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Tags]') AND type in (N'U'))
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Tags
GO

if NOT EXISTS (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'Tags' and column_name = 'Id')
  alter table MyTable add MyColumn int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
GO

-- add new primary key constraint on new column   
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tags 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tags
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
GO
```

I can't find an example on the second piece of code. But I can imagine that a table can't be created with 0 columns.

Any suggestions?

[Edit]
Some more context. Some tables exists some don't. Some columns exists some don't. I want to creat a script which could be executed anytime without breaking or causing error msg's like the table/column already exists.

Comment: don't write code that create tables on-the-fly?

Comment: Question is not well written. There should be more details. Are you looking for a table without a column or create a column on a table if the column doesnot exist already?

Comment: It's not possible, unfortunately. There are a number of places where the SQL language falls short of what you might expect from a truly Set-based language (i.e. empty sets are interesting, but SQL doesn't allow tables or keys with an empty set of columns)

Comment: I edited my post for more context. But reading the responses, this is not possible, right?

Comment: [Interestingly, this is possible in PostgreSQL](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/17/creating-tables-dum-and-dee-in-postgresql/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can acheive what you're trying using the following:

Create the table with the ID and only check for the existence of the `Id` column if you didn't have to create the table.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Tags]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].Tags (Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    if NOT EXISTS (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'Tags' and column_name = 'Id')
    BEGIN
        alter table [dbo].Tags add MyColumn int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

        -- add new primary key constraint on new column   
        ALTER TABLE dbo.Tags 
        ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tags
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    END
ELSE

GO
```

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
create table tab
```

raises an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'tab'.

and this code

```
 create table tab1
 (
   id int
 )

 alter table tab1 drop id
```

raises an error

> ALTER TABLE 'tab1' failed. Dropping all columns in a table is not
>   allowed.

so a table without columns is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't create table without columns in SQL Server, but if the table doesn't exist before you create it, it doesn't have any column, so why don't you simply create it?

If this is a kind of upgrade script you might do an ELSE branch where you check for each column before adding it.

Comment: "Of course" may be a bit strong. In Relational theory (that SQL was meant to be trying to follow), Relations with no Attributes are still interesting. (As are, e.g. Keys containing no Attributes, which implies a Relation that can only contain 0 or 1 Tuple)

Comment: I knew that, but as this question was tagged [sql-server] i didn't want to confuse the poster ;-) Now i added "in SQL Server"...